# Show plus sign icon and specify indent for child items tkinter treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, icons, indentation

I'm building a list of items with subitems using python 3 tkinter treeview.  My treeview has three columnms.  Very simply, i want to show that little +/- icon on each item which has children items.  For some reason it doesn't appear.   Also, the children items are showing up directly under the parent items.  So with no plus icon and no indent, it's impossible to tell which items are under which parent.  It just looks like a list.  I can't find in the docs where it specifies "turn on plus icon" or "set indent of child items"

What i'm going for:

[image]

What I got (it still lets me hide/show "items" under each "tube" by double clicking the "Tube" line):

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's some sample code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import random


sub = tk.Toplevel()
result_frame = tk.Frame(sub)
result_frame.pack()

treeview_widget_frame = tk.Frame(result_frame)
treeview_widget_frame.pack(side = 'top')

columns = ['a','b','c']
tubes = 10

treeview_widget = ttk.Treeview(treeview_widget_frame, height = 20, columns = columns, show = 'headings')

for col in columns:
    treeview_widget.heading(col, text = col.title(), command = lambda c=col: sortby(treeview_widget, c, 0))

for n in range(int(tubes)):
    treeview_widget.insert('', tk.END, text = 'Tube ' + str(n+1), iid = n, values = ('Tube ' + str(n+1), "",""), open = 'True')
    print(n)

for t in range(15):
    r = random.randint(0,9)
    treeview_widget.insert(r, tk.END, values = ['Item ' + str(t), '12345', 'details'])

treeview_widget.pack()
    

sub.mainloop()
```

Comment: So you mean, that the text have to change dynamicly whenever you click on to plus or minus?

Comment: Jut added some more info to help clarify.

Comment: You are giving the option `show = 'headings'` when creating the treeview, so you are telling tkinter to hide the tree part (default is `show = 'tree headings'` which shows both the column headings and the tree)

Comment: Thanks @j_4321.  This works.   Can you point toward the docs that explain the details?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the tcl/tk [documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_treeview.htm#M11), the `Treeview` widget has a `show` option to choose which parts of the widget to display. It takes a string among:

- `"tree headings"` (default)
- `"tree"`
- `"headings"`
- `""`

`headings` corresponds to the column headings and `tree` corresponds to the 0-th column `#0` which contains the + icons to expand/collapse items.

Since you create the `Treeview` with

```
treeview_widget = ttk.Treeview(..., show='headings')
```

then you are telling tkinter to hide the tree part, which is why you cannot see the + icons. To restore them, create the tree either with `show='tree headings'` or without passing the option since this is the default value.